# Python TypeError: not enough arguments for format string while writing csv

Tags: python, csv

I want to write certain fields in very column of a csv file. I did the following

```
fp.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s, %s,%s,%s,%s" % ('SR NO.','DATE','START TIME','END TIME'+'CITY','HEADEND','HEADEND TYPE','CHANNEL','PROMO ORDER','PRODUCT','PROMO NAME','VARIANT','VIDEO NAME'))
```

Which is 13 %s for 13 fields.But it gives error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

I also tried

```
fp.write("{0}\t {1} \t {2} \t {3} \t {4} \t {5} \t {6} \t {7} \t {8} \t {9} \t {10} \t {11} \t {12}" .format('SR NO.','DATE','START TIME','END TIME'+'CITY','HEADEND','HEADEND TYPE','CHANNEL','PROMO ORDER','PRODUCT','PROMO NAME','VARIANT','VIDEO NAME'))
```

which again gives the error
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Please suggest me how to write these many fields in csv file as columns.

Comment: Why not just use the `csv` library?

Comment: you have 13 %s and 12 arguments to %

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. The first rule of debugging is to assume the error message is telling you the literal truth.

Answer (score 1):

You can use join:

```
l = ['SR NO.','DATE','START TIME','END TIME'+'CITY','HEADEND','HEADEND TYPE','CHANNEL','PROMO ORDER','PRODUCT','PROMO NAME','VARIANT','VIDEO NAME']
fp.write(','.join(l))
```

Btw you have 12 fields not 13. Change 'END TIME'+'CITY' to 'END TIME', 'CITY'

Though I think you might want to take a look at the CSV-library of python. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Yes but the problem is .join prints everyting in one cell and not in subsequent columns. And 'END TIME'+'CITY' was the mistake. Thanks a lot. Need to pay attention while debugging :(

Answer (score 0):

You only have 12 arguments, this is the problem:

```
'END TIME'+'CITY'
```

the 2 strings will be concatenated into a single value before the substitution takes place. Change it to this and you should be fine:

```
'END TIME', 'CITY'
```

Answer (score 0):

you do have only 12 parameters in there, 'END TIME'+'CITY' is considered one parameter, because you are concatenating two strings into one.

Answer (score 0):

There is only 12 argument in your problem,

```
'END TIME'+ 'CITY' = 'END TIMECITY'
```

which make it one
or if you want to use it as one string use `format` like this:-

```
data = ('SR NO.','DATE','START TIME','END TIME'+'CITY','HEADEND','HEADEND TYPE','CHANNEL','PROMO ORDER','PRODUCT','PROMO NAME','VARIANT','VIDEO NAME'
)
['{}'.format(i) for i in data]

>>> 
['SR NO.', 'DATE', 'START TIME', 'END TIMECITY', 'HEADEND', 'HEADEND TYPE', 'CHANNEL', 'PROMO ORDER', 'PRODUCT', 'PROMO NAME', 'VARIANT', 'VIDEO NAME']
```